# Saving (2^52) Number in a C data type

Tags: c, data-structures

I am doing a Project using c , and I encountered a Problem while doing some calculations.. actually I want to store a big number (2^52) in any data type

```
int helper = TwoOf(26);//52 over 2

unsigned long long help = helper * helper;
```

> - function Twoof(x) -> calculates x^2
>
> I used long long to store 2^52 but the debugger shows it has a zero value.

can anyone help?

Comment: `unsigned long long` is not enough to store result of `2^52`. Instead use _int array of required size_

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide a [mcve] ?  This will probably help your question being well received and other person to help you.

Comment: `helper` is `int` so `helper * helper` is too. You assign it to an `unsigned long long` but this is too late. You need to start your calculations with long long.

Comment: @achal Please elaborate in view of the likely size of `unsigned long long` of 8 bytes, with 64 bits. Consider using extended space and formatting features of making an answer.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of your "(2^52)" (which is usually interpreted as 2 to the power of 52 by most readers) in relation to "52 over 2", which might refer to a very different mathmatical construct/expression. E.g.  "4 over 2" equals 6 (I hope, being a little rusty there....), while "2 to the power of 4" equals 16. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: @Yunnosch it is `52/2`... `2^(52/2)` is the positive square root of `2^52`...

Comment: You just need to type your `helper` as `unsigned long long` or, *alternatively*, cast one operand to `unsigned long long` in the multiplication: `(unsigned long long)helper * helper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not require single digit accuracy and are happy with a number of significant figures, use a `double`

Comment: Funnily enough, an IEEE754 `double` can store 2^52 exactly. (It starts to go awry after the 53rd power.) Occasionally this is a good idea especially if you compiler doesn't have a `long long` type and fast floating point; +1.